# Using jQuery().trim() in select tag?

Tags: jquery, html, select

#### HTML

```
<select name="tree">
<option>All</option>
    <option id="sel_cat" value="1"> &nbsp Activity</option>
    <option id="sel_cat" value="2"> &nbsp Alert</option>
    <option id="sel_cat" value="3"> &nbsp &nbsp Lead</option>
    <option id="sel_cat" value="4"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Notification</option>
</select>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$('#sel_cat').change(function(){
      // do some
});
```

Can I trim spaces in view select, but when click on select spaces remained.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Did you consider using `optgroup`?

Comment: Sorry @Florent we seemed to be conflicting - I'll leave you to it!

Comment: And do not use same id on options. Ids must be unique. Use it on select. Get all options with `$('#sel_cat > option')`.

Comment: &nbsp without a trailing ;? Should be &nbsp;

Comment: Why do you use spaces and not css margin!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better approach:

```
$("#sel_cat > option").each(function () {
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Cn2c9/)

**FYI:** *`id`*'s should be unique

Based on your comments,

```
$("#sel_cat").on('change', function () {
 $( "#sel_cat option:selected" ).html($( "#sel_cat option:selected" ).html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''))
});
```

**[JSFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Cn2c9/2/)**

Comment: I need when choosing a tree retains its form with blanks, and when I select an item in the chosen selective spaces removed

Comment: Work, but if I select again spaces is gone

Comment: @user2798470 There is no way to keep history but someway possible..  let me try

Comment: I can do this use style css with padding for levels in tree, but this not work on Mac OS X browsers (((

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trim spaces from a string (that's what I read from your question) you can extend the String object with this code

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
 String.prototype.trim = function() {
  return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
 }
}
```

and use it to trim spaces like this

```
str.trim();
```

If you also need to trim non breakable spaces `&nbsp;` you have to add the following

```
.replace(/&nbsp;/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="tree" id="sel_cat">
<option>All</option>
    <option value="1"> &nbsp; Activity</option>
    <option value="2"> &nbsp; Alert</option>
    <option value="3"> &nbsp; &nbsp; Lead</option>
    <option value="4"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Notification</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#sel_cat').change(function(){
    //your code
    $.trim($(this).html());
    //your code
});
```

Comment: this won't work.  You're doing for `value` not the text within option try my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use below code :

```
$('#mySelect').change(function(){
     alert($.trim($(this)[0].options[$(this)[0].selectedIndex].text));
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<select name="tree" id="mySelect">
    <option>All</option>
    <option value="1"> &nbsp Activity</option>
    <option value="2"> &nbsp Alert</option>
    <option value="3"> &nbsp &nbsp Lead</option>
    <option value="4"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp Notification</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cant share same ID with multiple elements!

Answer (score -1):

For a start, you use the same ID for multiple elements. Don't. Use class or another selector instead - I think you want to target the select and not the options. Also, it's not `&nbsp` - it's `&nbsp;`. Also, your code never calls `trim()`, so I guess that the issue is not with the trim, but rather the selectors. Do you see the change event fire?

```
<select name="tree" id="mySelect">
    <option>All</option>
    <option class="sel_cat" value="1"> &nbsp; Activity</option>
    <option class="sel_cat" value="2"> &nbsp; Alert</option>
    <option class="sel_cat" value="3"> &nbsp; &nbsp Lead</option>
    <option class="sel_cat" value="4"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Notification</option>
</select>

$('#mySelect').change(function(){
    alert($.trim($(this).val()));
});
```

That should do what I think you want. See http://jsfiddle.net/LAWDU/ for a live example

Comment: Btw, if you really do want to alert the *value* of the selected option, trimming makes no sense because the values are integers and don't contain whitespace.